# Search and delete all tar.gz files on centos 6

Tags: centos

I need to free up some disk space on my web server and would like to ask if running the command below would break anything?
My server is running centos 6 with cpanel/whm.

$ find / -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -exec rm -i {} \;

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I will investigate further following your instructions and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll lose logs if they are already compressed, or uploaded files if any. By default there shouldn't be any of those files on installed system. Personally I think this is wrong to just jettison what you can instead of trying to find the cause.

You can try finding what's occupying space by running:

```
du -hs / # shows how much root directory occupies
```

Compare that to the output of:

```
df -h # shows used space on disks
```

If the number didn't match by a far - you probably have unclosed deleted files and a simple reboot will reclaim this space for you.

If not you can proceed by recursively doing:

```
cd <dir>; du -hs * # enter directory and calculate size of its contents
```

You can do that starting from `/` and proceeding to the biggest dir. After all you'll find your source of free space. :)

PS: CentOS doesn't compress logs by default. You will not detect those logs by searching for archived files, but they can be huge. Compressing them is an easy way to get some space:

1. Turn on compression in `/etc/logrotate.conf`:

   ```
   compress
   ```
2. Compress already rotated logs with:

   ```
   cd /var/log; find . -type f | grep '.*-[0-9]\+$' | xargs -n1 gzip -9
   ```